# Approximation of an integral

Tags: integration

)
I can't get over a step in my teacher's exercise.

$$I(x) = 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{y^3 + 4y^2}{y^2+4y+5} dy = 2\int_{0}^{1} y dy  -5\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2y}{y^2+4y+5} dy$$

Probably it's very easy..

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that:
$$\begin{align*}
2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{y^3 + 4y^2}{y^2+4y+5} dy
&= 2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{y(y^2+4y+5)−5y}{y^2+4y+5} dy \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{1} \left( \frac{y(y^2+4y+5)}{y^2+4y+5} - \frac{5y}{y^2+4y+5}\right) dy \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{1} \left( y - \frac{5y}{y^2+4y+5}\right) dy \\
&= 2\left(\int_{0}^{1}  y~dy - \int_{0}^{1}\frac{5y}{y^2+4y+5}dy \right) \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{1}  y~dy - 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{5y}{y^2+4y+5}dy \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{1} y~dy  -5\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2y}{y^2+4y+5} dy
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

$\textbf{Hint: } y^3+4y^2 = y(y^2+4y+5)-5y$